# Enabling touch stimulation changes css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Here is my HTML site
[image]

Here is the site in mobile view (with touch stimulation disabled)
[image]

Now, when touch stimulation enabled

[image]

Why does the style change when enabling touch?
Here is my code:

```css
body {
    background:rgba(71, 71, 71, 0.3);
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    color: #fff;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 80vh;
    width: 65%;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 1100px;

    background: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}


.sub {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 16px;;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}


.float_l {
    float: left;
}

.float_r {
    float: right;
}

/* For Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .main {
        min-width: 350px;
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;

        margin: 8vh auto;

        position: relative;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

    }

    .float_l {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .float_r {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">

</head>


<body>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="sub float_l">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac nisi elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent in tellus eget turpis elementum facilisis quis vitae odio. Aliquam sollicitudin ante eget felis tristique, eu dapibus est laoreet. Fusce interdum, lorem faucibus sagittis tincidunt, tellus mi facilisis eros, a convallis lacus nisl at ligula. Aliquam rhoncus laoreet ultricies. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent elit elit, rhoncus vitae ligula sit amet, porttitor imperdiet sem. Nulla rhoncus nibh rutrum, accumsan nisi at, commodo sem. Sed id mi eu dui bibendum suscipit. Vivamus massa justo, tempus vitae lacus blandit, iaculis cursus orci. Praesent molestie, quam non sodales aliquam, justo orci rhoncus tellus, vitae tempor nisl felis et diam. Curabitur sed ultricies lacus. Cras id orci augue.
        </div>

        <div class="sub float_r">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac nisi elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent in tellus eget turpis elementum facilisis quis vitae odio. Aliquam sollicitudin ante eget felis tristique, eu dapibus est laoreet. Fusce interdum, lorem faucibus sagittis tincidunt, tellus mi facilisis eros, a convallis lacus nisl at ligula. Aliquam rhoncus laoreet ultricies. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent elit elit, rhoncus vitae ligula sit amet, porttitor imperdiet sem. Nulla rhoncus nibh rutrum, accumsan nisi at, commodo sem. Sed id mi eu dui bibendum suscipit. Vivamus massa justo, tempus vitae lacus blandit, iaculis cursus orci. Praesent molestie, quam non sodales aliquam, justo orci rhoncus tellus, vitae tempor nisl felis et diam. Curabitur sed ultricies lacus. Cras id orci augue. 
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

I need the divs to be horizontal on desktops and vertical on mobiles. I have used @media screen and (max-width: 950px) to achieve that. But it doesn't seem to work when touch stimulation is enabled.

Comment: Are you using firefox browser?

Comment: Try adding this to your head. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`

Comment: I'll make an answer then.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a line for a responsive viewport in your `<head>`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[More info on this from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)